# Plotting two axes in gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot, axes

Is it possible to plot two curves, with two corresponding axes in gnuplot, each of which has a different scale?

For example, `y=x**2` and `y=x**4` in the same graph (they vary enough to be "uncomfortable" when plotted with the same scale).

Comment: @Kazark - Would you mind explaining what was the point of that edit? To make the question non-compatible with both answers, or?

Comment: @Idigas There was of course no intention of obscuring the question. If you think I have done so, you can of course roll back the edit.

Comment: @Kazark - So why the edit then?

Comment: Why not to accept one of answers?

Answer (score 57):

You can have the axes handled automatically without you having to scale them yourself and keep auto-scaling:

```
set terminal jpeg
set output 'graph.jpg'

set xrange [-10:10]
set ytics 10 nomirror tc lt 1
set ylabel '2*x' tc lt 1
set y2tics 20 nomirror tc lt 2
set y2label '4*x' tc lt 2
plot 2*x linetype 1, 4*x linetype 2 axes x1y2
```

[image: output of the script]

Comment: As my axes naturally have a different scale, I found `autofreq` useful.  e.g. `set ytics autofreq tc lt 1`

Answer (score 15):

It is possible to set different ranges for y and y2 (the right axes), and even to set the color of the labels/tics independently.

Then we simply divide the second function by 2 (or something appropriate) and set the colors... as in this example:

```
set xrange [-10:10]
set yrange [-20:20]
set y2range [-40:40]

set ytics 10 nomirror tc lt 1
set ylabel '2*x' tc lt 1

set y2tics 20 nomirror tc lt 2
set y2label '4*x' tc lt 2

plot 2*x linetype 1, 4*x/2+.5 linetype 2
```