# Set two y axes is gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have 2 files with points

```
C:\1.txt
C:\2.txt
```

I'm trying to plot both of them into the same plot.

```
set style line 1 lc rgb '#0060ad' lt 2 lw 2 pt 0 ps 1.5
plot 'C:\1.txt' with linespoints ls 1 , 'C:\2.txt' with linespoints ls 1
```

How to set 2 different y-axis range for them ([0:6000] and [0:150] for example)?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2827650/7010554 ?

Answer (score 3):

[link to documentation](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.5/multiaxis.html)

i've got it.

```
set yrange [0:6000]
set y2range [0:150]
set xrange [0:5]
set x2range [0:5]
set y2tics
plot 'C:\1.txt' axes x1y1 with lines , 'C:\2.txt' axes x2y2 with line
```

Comment: You don't need the x2range, simply use `x1y2`